# logstash: how to "bundle update logstash-codec-plain"

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to add an extra plugin to an machine running logstash.

I can't load the plugin directly from the internet because the internet isn't accessible from this host.

I tried exporting an offline copy of the plugin from a VM using:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin prepare-offline-pack --output logstash-output-syslog.zip logstash-output-syslog
```

But the plugin won't load on the target machine, it complains about the version of logstash-codec-plain.

I tried to downgrade the version of logstash-codec-plain on the VM, so that I could re-export the right version, but that didn't work:

```
"The bundle currently has logstash-codec-plain locked at 3.1.0.  Try running `bundle update logstash-codec-plain`"
```

I don't know what it means to to `` run `bundle update` ``.

I tried to delete `logstash-codec-plain`, in the hope that I could then reinstall a lower version, that didn't work either:

```
Failed to remove "logstash-codec-plain" because the following plugins or libraries depend on it:
* logstash-mixin-aws
* logstash-mixin-http_client
```

I don't know why it complained about these specific two plugins, I'd already removed both of them, as well as a lot of other plugins.

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin remove logstash-mixin-aws
...
ERROR: Operation aborted, cannot remove plugin, message: This plugin has not been previously installed
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I uninstalled logstash from the VM and reinstalled the oldest version of logstash that I could find, in the hope that it would have an old enough version of `logstash-codec-plain`.

And it worked! (*)

But it's hardly elegant, flexible or a precise way to downgrade a single plugin to a specific version. I was just lucky that the downgrade delivered exactly the right version.

Better answers would be welcome.

(*) Worked, once I used `chown -R logstash:logstash ...` on the newly installed directories.